# error- Data at the root level is invalid Line 1 position 1.

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Please check the code. I'm getting this error even after using doc.Load() function.

```
Application.DoEvents();
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
xmldoc.Load(fs); 
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Source");
```

Check the code in : https://pastebin.com/4U7qa1L4

Comment: Please add xml. It is invalid

Comment: Double check if path to file is valid

Comment: Without a [mcve] -- specifically a sample of XML that causes the problem -- we have no way to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the extra hidden files from XML folder. It should not contain any files other than ".xml". Also you have to use `xmlfile.Load()` instead of `xmlfile.xmlLoad()`.